# Ruler Tool in C#

Tags: c#, measurement, angle, rulers

I need to make a tool that allows to, Measure screen distances by using a ruler.

I currently have no code for either of these tools, any code for measuring distances and angles would be much appreicated.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Did you try thinking about the problem and coming out with probable implementations that can solve your problem? If yes, what did you come up with?

Comment: Voting to close as question is too broad to actually answer, also, asker has phrased it (possibly un intentionally) as a "plez senz deh codz" question.

Comment: "Code 4 me." Show you've done effort yourself, and what you are unable of to figure out yourself. StackOverflow is not a bunch of code monkeys.

Answer (score 3):

Do you really need to *make* it, or do you just need it?

If you just need it, [ScreenCalipers](http://www.iconico.com/caliper/) could be your friend:

[image]
<sub>(source: [iconico.com](http://www.iconico.com/caliper/caliperHoriz.jpg))</sub>

(It's not free, but at $29.50, you'd have to be paid a *very* low hourly rate to be cheaper coding it yourself)

Comment: I found jRuler (http://www.spadixbd.com/freetools/jruler.htm) to be a simple and free tool for measuring on screen (It's not capable of measuring angles though).

Answer (score 1):

You can find ruler here

- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/ruler.aspx

Comment: this tool looks like it would be more useful if they either got rid of the standard window, or at least made the dialog background more transparent so you can measure right up against the rulers!

Comment: @Dave, yes but its not hard to do it.